# Unknown usage of HDD Space

Tags: linux, hard-disk, ext4, webserver, storage

I have a VPS with CentoS 7 that is robbing me of 68GB of space. My server has 160GB of storage. It says it is using 120GB. But my server should only be using about 50GB - 65Gb.

I found that there is a file in the root that is 68GB with file name of "." when I ran (`du -h --max-depth=1`) which I thought was the sum total being used but when I run (`du -cksh *`) the total is actually 60GB.

Can there be a hidden file with no name for 68GB?

```
[root@srv ~]# df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda        154G  122G   31G  80% /
[root@srv ~]# 


[root@srv /]# df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.1G     0  4.1G   0% /dev
tmpfs           4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           4.2G   12M  4.1G   1% /run
tmpfs           4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda        165G  131G   33G  80% /
/dev/sdc         85G   40G   41G  49% /mnt/DRIVE1
tmpfs           821M     0  821M   0% /run/user/0
[root@srv /]# 


[root@srv ~]# lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 156.3G  0 disk /
sdb    8:16   0   3.8G  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc    8:32   0    80G  0 disk /mnt/DRIVE1
[root@srv ~]# 


[root@srv ~]# du -h --max-depth=1
16K ./.local
156M    ./.cache
7.0M    ./.acme.sh
4.0K    ./.spamassassin
8.0K    ./.ssh
9.3M    ./.npm
56K ./.razor
48K ./.subversion
20K ./.config
35M ./.composer
4.0K    ./.conf
11M ./node_modules
129M    ./jail
8.0K    ./.pki
8.0K    ./.cwp_sessions
346M    .
[root@srv ~]# cd /
[root@srv /]# du -h --max-depth=1
318M    ./boot
4.3M    ./tmp
6.6G    ./usr
0   ./sys
20G ./home
4.0K    ./.trash
0   ./dev
1.7G    ./opt
2.8G    ./var
16K ./lost+found
36K ./.channels
11M ./run
4.0K    ./srv
37G ./mnt
265M    ./root
4.0K    ./media
du: cannot access ‘./proc/24037/task/24037/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/24037/task/24037/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/24037/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘./proc/24037/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
0   ./proc
43M ./etc
68G .
[root@srv /]# 


[root@srv /]# du -cksh *
16K aquota.group
16K aquota.user
0   bin
318M    boot
0   dev
44M etc
12G home
0   lib
0   lib64
16K lost+found
4.0K    media
37G mnt
1.7G    opt
du: cannot access ‘proc/24756/task/24756/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/24756/task/24756/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/24756/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/24756/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   proc
4.0K    razor-agent.log
311M    root
11M run
0   sbin
0   scripts
4.0K    srv
0   sys
4.3M    tmp
6.5G    usr
2.8G    var
60G total
[root@srv /]#
```

Comment: Besides the filesystem changing sizes mid-question, I think you probably have a large file in the root directory. Check with `ls -al /`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the good news is you don't have a big file called '.'. That's just the summary for the current directory.

I'd throw `-a` into your `du` flags to see filenames too.

If that doesn't show you anything new you might want to check the output of `lsof | grep deleted` to see if maybe there's a process running that tried to delete a file but still has it open.

Another thing I'd check is to make sure `/mnt` was written to without anything mounted in there.

Comment: "Another thing I'd check is to make sure /mnt was written to without anything mounted in there." Brilliant! that was the problem. I unmounted the /dev/sdc and deleted the directory< then created it again and remounted the drive> i now have plenty of room!